# .sports-changed-status should be changed to .sports-last-second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

- I am new to Reactjs.
- If the staus is active. I need to update the p tag and need to update in my `liClass` as `.sports-last-second`
- `.sports-changed-status` should be changed to `.sports-last-second`
- I have created a if condition but not sure how to insert.
- Can you guys tell how to do it.
- Providng my code below.

  ```
  newContentAdded: function () {

  var firstTab = 'got-the-value';

  if (firstTab == 'got-the-value')
  {
   <p> got-the-value got-the-value got-the-value got-the-value </p>
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you provide the entire component you've created?

Comment: Javascript variable names can't contain a hyphen. (e.g. "first-tab" should read "firstTab")

Comment: @BenHare my fiddle has the whole component...after changing in js...I will add new styles to this class .sports-changed-status

Comment: @JeffMcCloud ok...can you tell me how to implement the functionality

Comment: just a note, using `.bind()` in render is extremely slow!

Comment: @LeoNapoleon can you update in fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you already have all the necessary code to do this.

```
var isActive = this.state.selected === index;
```

You have this line to determine if your tab is active. You then use the next to lines of code to set context based on the value:

```
var activeClass = (isActive ? 'active' : '');
var content = isActive ? this.props.children[this.state.selected] : null;
```

You can apply something similar to what you've done with `content` and `activeClass`. Take a look at how you implement them.

```
return (
    <li role="presentation" key={index} className={child.props.liClass}>
        <a href="#" 
        className={`sports-tab-header ${activeClass}`} // <== Adds active class
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)}>
        <h2>{child.props.label}</h2>
        <p className="sports-subtitle">{child.props.subtitle}</p>
      </a>

      <div className="tabs__content">
        {content} // <== Adds content only if active
      </div>

    </li>
  );
```

So changing the content of the `<p>` tag would be just a small change:

```
var newContent = <span>Hello</span>;
var pContent = isActive ? newContent : child.props.subtitle;
...

// Use the pContent variable instead of child.props.subtitle
<p className="sports-subtitle">{pContent}</p>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e767txs/41/)

The modification of the className will be the same as how this line is handled with `activeClass`:

```
....
className={`sports-tab-header ${activeClass}`}
```

That should be simple enough to handle.

Comment: thanks for your reply...I need to change content inside this p tag <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2"> ....is it possible???

Comment: It is. Create the `div` and `p` tags inside your `Pane` render function instead of the `App` Render function. Then you can tweak your code to pass the `selected` state down into the `Pane` so you can do the necessary logic. That will require a lot of changes though, since right now `Pane` has no concept of what's in `Tab`. You should outfit each `Tab` to render a `Pane`. I'd really recommend following the [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html).

Comment: I tried updating in the fiddle...its not working....can you update in the fiddle.....

Comment: I have some doubt...can you help me with it.. I tried but its not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563436/i-tried-to-change-es5-to-es6-classes

Comment: can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600485/trying-to-change-all-the-components-into-es6