# Trying to change all the components into es6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to change all the components into es6
- I did for two but not sure how to do for the third one.
- can you tell me how to change it?
- providing my code below.

  ```
  export default class FirstTimeTab extends React.Component{

    getInitialState(){
      return {
         'panes' : [

          <div className="sports-tab-content">
              <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">
  ```

Comment: `working fiddle` doesn't

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry I didn't get you??

Comment: the fiddle you say is working doesn't

Comment: @JaromandaX can you complete your sentence...did you not type something

Comment: it is complete ... you state you have a working fiddle ... I'm telling you the fiddle doesn't work

Comment: @JaromandaX can you help me now...I updated questio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had multiple small errors, one after another, that needed to be fixed. I highly recommend you make smaller changes so you can track more easily what goes wrong during development.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e767txs/64/)

First, remove `export default` from `export default class FirstTimeTab extends React.Component`. This isn't necessary when working in a single-file Fiddle like we are doing here.

That leaves you with

```
class FirstTimeTab extends React.Component {
  ...
```

Running from there will give you the console error that `App` is undefined:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Which is entirely true, since you changed `App` to `FirstTimeTab`. 
After changing this to use `<FirstTimeTab />`, you'll get yet another helpful console error that:

```
> getInitialState was defined on FirstTimeTab, a plain JavaScript class. This is
only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to
define a state property instead?
```

This message is pretty clear: you can't use `getInitialState` with the `class` syntax. Instead, change to the more clear method of setting the initial `state` property in the `constructor`:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    'panes' : [
       <div className="sports-tab-content">
       ...
```

Finally, you still won't see anything until you properly display your content. You were setting the content in the `content` attribute of each `Pane`, when it seems like the rest of your code expects it to be passed as `children` (which is the more correct way in React):

```
render () {
  return (
    <Tabs selected={0} changeContent={this.changeContent}>
      <Pane label="Account Setup" subtitle="Days 1 and 2" liClass="sports-setup-ico first-time-active ft-active-tab">
        {this.state.panes[0]} // Content passed as children
      </Pane>
     ...
```

Edit for followup:

You've been specifying required props with these bits of code:

```
Pane.propTypes = {
  label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired
};
```

The above states, for examples, that you require a `label` and `children` for the `Pane`.

If your error is *Required prop `content` was not specified in `Pane`*, this means somewhere in your code you are requiring `content` as an attribute. In my answer above, I recommended you switch from passing your content in `content` to passing it through the `children` property. If you followed that advice, just remove the line that causes this requirement. It should look like the piece of code I added above, though I saw no evidence of that in your original Fiddles. Maybe it was something you added later.

Comment: I integrated in my codebase but still I am getting the below error...any idea about it   ----------> Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `content` was not specified in `Pane`. Check the render method of `FirstTimeTab`.

Comment: Edited my answer above with a response to your follow-up. These error logs are helpful; try to take the time to fully comprehend them and re-read the React documentation. If you have more problems after this, look at the updated Fiddle I posted; it works just fine. Any problems remaining after that may need to be in a new question.

Comment: but still I am seeing this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'panes' of undefined(…)  tab conent is not changing...can you tell the reason

Comment: it should add new tab content...now its not adding new tab content

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e767txs/64/) I posted. Try to compare that to what you have. In my version, there are no errors and the tab content is changing.

Comment: can you tell me why I am not seeing this text...when i click second tab...previously I was seeing in my old fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9e767txs/65/          `         this.props.changeContent(0 ,  <p> got-the-value got-the-value got-the-value got-the-value </p>); `

Comment: That problem is answered by [the answer from Eric Kambestad](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40600623/7016732). See this updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e767txs/68/).

Comment: can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687317/swapping-css-classes-for-the-div-in-react

Comment: .can you help me with one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776856/remove-css-class-when-we-switch-tab-from-li-tag

Comment: can you help me with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832723/make-three-components-into-two-components

Answer (score 0):

`this` is unavailable in that method.. when you call `this.changeContent` on line 60 change it to `this.changeContent.bind(this)`.  That will bind your component instance to the method.

you can also do this in a constructor if you want to by adding:
`this.changeContent = this.changeContent.bind(this)` inside the constructor below `super(props)`, then you can use the method as you have it

Can read more about `bind` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: it didnt work...I update my question...can you help me

Comment: Well in your non-working fiddle you are trying to render <App /> which does not exist in that js file.  Also, in a fiddle you don't need to export your classes.. this is throwing an error.  Fix those things and it may get you a little further in to what's actually wrong with the code.